# github pages serve javascript / d3 visualizations

Tags: javascript, github, d3.js, markdown, github-pages

I'd like to serve javascript scripts and have them run such that people can go to my *.github.io page and see the visualizations there.

Is this possible? If so, how might I embed the javascript into the markdown?

Comment: You can use HTML and Javascript directly in those pages.

Comment: how? I didn't think markdown specification had javascript.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't have to use markdown. You can write plain HTML with Javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Markdown Syntax Overview](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

I'm sure there's a better way to include scripts in your project, but if you really want to embed them in your markdown, there shouldn't be anything stopping you from doing the following:

```
# This is a title

> this is a blockquote

<script>
  // this is a script that renders a chart
  var chart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
     // ...etc...
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to set up a [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/):

> This is a simple viewer for code examples hosted on GitHub Gist. Code up an example using Gist, and then point people here to view the example and the source code, live!
>
> The main source code for your example should be named index.html. You can also include a README.md using Markdown, and a thumbnail.png for preview. The index.html can use relative links to other files in your Gist; you can also use absolute links to shared files, such as D3, jQuery and Leaflet.

Otherwise, you can embed stuff using `<iframe>`.

Comment: Needs to be for a blog. So not sure that's what I want.